Combinatorics Problem: Number of ways placing non-attacking unlabeled rooks only on white squares on a chess board
I have the following problem from a textbook:
"Two rooks on a chess board are non-attacking if they are not in the same row and not in the same column. For a positive integer $n$, let $X_n$ be the number of ways one can place
$2n$ unlabeled rooks on a $2n × 2n$ chess board such that they are pairwise non-attacking and every rook is on a white square."
Use the Inclusion-Exclusion-Principle to show that for each $n \geq 1$:
$X_{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}^{2}(2n-k)!k!$
What I have so far:
First, let $Z$ define the ground set that is the set of all arrangements of $2n$ pairwise non-attacking rooks.
Following the Inclusion-Exclusion-Principle, I define some sets $Z_{i}$ with some "bad property" in terms of $i$ (in this case non-attacking arrangements in which at least one rook is on a black square), such that,
$X_{n} = |Z - \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} Z_{i}| = |Z| - |\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} Z_{i}|$,
i.e., from all non-attacking arrangements I discard those in which there is at least one rook on a black square. That being said, I fail to come up with a proper definition of such "bad property" sets $Z_{i}$ such that I can properly count $|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} Z_{i}|$ for the desired value $X_{n}$. For example, I tried to define $Z_{i}$ such that $Z_{i}$ contains every arrangement such that on the $i$-th row there is a rook on a black square.
Any help how to count $X_{n}$ properly, in particular using Inclusion-Exclusion-Principle, is appreciated.
Edit: I know that by a straightforward counting argument, one can see that the answer is $X_{n} = (n!)^{2}$. That being said, my textbook wants me to use Inclusion-Exclusion, in particular, I am also interested in how to solve it by using Inclusion-Exclusion to obtain the desired sum, for the sake of practicing PIE.

You had the right idea to let the bad property be that, for each row, that the rook in that row is on a black square. However, the formula is a sum from $k=0$ to $k=n$, which suggests that there are only $n$ bad properties, whereas there are $2n$ rows.
The key idea is this; you apply PIE to counting arrangements where we only require that even-numbered rows rows must have their rooks on white squares. This seems like a different problem, but it is equivalent to the original. This is because whenever you place $2n$ rooks an a $2n\times 2n$ board, with one rook per row and column, then the number of rooks on black squares in even rows always equals the number of rooks on black squares in odd rows. I advise you to first prove the claim in the previous sentence, and then solve the problem using PIE. You can check your work against the detailed solution below.

 Given a placement of $2n$ rooks on a $2n\times 2n$ board, let $b_e$ be the number of rooks on black squares in even rows, and let $b_o$ be the number of rooks on black squares in odd rows. I claimed $b_e=b_o$, and I prove this now.

 Define $w_e$ and $w_o$ similarly, counting rooks on white squares in even and odd rows. We have $b_e+w_e=n$, because there are $n$ rooks in even rows, each on a black or white square. Furthermore, it is true that $b_o+w_e=n$. Say that the square in the first row and first column is colored white. There are $n$ total rooks in the even-numbered columns. Each rook in an even-numbered column is either in an odd row, and therefore on a black square, or it is on an even row, and hence on a white square, so in total $b_o+w_e=n$. Combining these two equations proves $b_e=b_o$.

 For each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $Z_i$ denote subset of arrangements in $Z$ for which the rook in the $(2i)^\text{th}$ row is on a black square. The PIE says that$$|Z-\bigcup_{i=1}^nZ_i|=\sum_{S\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}}(-1)^{|S|}\left|\bigcap_{i\in S}Z_i\right|=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk |Z_1\cap \dots \cap Z_k|$$
 (I adopt the convention that when $S=\varnothing$, $\bigcap_{i\in S}Z_i=Z$). We will be done if we can prove $|Z_1\cap \dots \cap Z_k|=\binom nkk!(2n-k)!$, which I do now. There are $k$ rooks which will be placed on black squares in rows numbered $2,4,\dots,2k$. There are $\binom nk$ ways to choose the $k$ columns these rooks will span (you can only select from the columns whose intersection with the even rows is black), and then $k!$ ways to place them on the $k^2$ black squares at the intersection of these $k$ rows and $k$ columns. Finally, there are $2n-k$ remaining rooks to place in the intersection of the remaining $2n-k$ rows and $2n-k$ columns, which can be done in $(2n-k)!$ ways.


+1 to your answer.  Nice analysis.

Clarification requested:  If I understand your analysis correctly, while it is true that $~b_o = b_e,~$ that isn't necessary for your overall analysis to be valid.  That is, it looks like it would be  sufficient that $~b_e > 0 \implies b_o > 0.~$  That is, it looks like this (weaker) implication, by itself, coupled with your PIE approach, would be sufficient to allow you to continue to ignore the odd numbered rows.  Is my understanding correct?

First of all, there should be a rock in each column indexed by $i=1,2,\dots,2n$ of the board. Secondly, you can immediately see that the rocks on even columns and odd columns never attack each other, because of parity. Hence, the problem is equivalent to placing $n$ rocks on $n\times n$ grid, on two separate grids. Since the number of ways to do it on one grid is $n!$ ($n$ possible rows for the firs rock, $n-1$ for the second, etc.) the answer is $(n!)^2$.


Hello, thanks for your answer. I see that the answer is $X_{n} = (n!)^{2}$. That being said, my textbook wants me to use Inclusion-Exclusion, in particular, I am also interested in how to solve it by using Inclusion-Exclusion to obtain the desired sum. I edited this in my question now.
